# JRException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, oracle, jasper-reports

I have an error using Jaspersoft Studio with Oracle Database.
As soon as there is some data, the following line

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_TYPE}.substring(0,1)=="R"? $F{REASON_DELETED}:$F{REASON_ADOC}]]></printWhenExpression>
```

throws the following error:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

I don't understand, why Jasper Studio would cast it to a Boolean, since it is defined as a String:

```
<field name="REASON_ADOC" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="REASON_DELETED" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

and the SQL is also fine to me:

```
NVL(cr.REASON_ADHOC,'-') AS reason_adoc,
NVL(cr.REASON_DELETED,'-') AS reason_deleted,
```

and also in the view/table:

```
REASON_DELETED  VARCHAR2(250)
REASON_ADHOC    VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, your expression returns a String. But `printWhenExpression` expects boolean expression as a content. According to [docs](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#printWhenExpression):

> printWhenExpression
>   Definition of a Boolean expression that will determine if the element or the band should be printed or not.

It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. You might want to use `textFieldExpression` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure I get it working now ... should have checked the printwhenexpression class!